# How do i get views field labels in the template file

Tags: 7, views, theming, entities

I am creating a view, and displaying view by using custom template files. As per theme suggestions I named the template file for fields as `views-view-fields--blog-display--page.tpl`. In this file I want to display labels for the view fields which i have given while adding fields. I tried using

```
<?php print $fields['label']->content; ?>
```

But not able to get the label. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see in the [documentation for views-view-fields.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-fields.tpl.php/7.x-3.x) (I did not test it myself), the syntax seems to be something like the following:

```
<?php print $fields['myfield']->label; ?>
```

(you can also use `$fields['myfield']->label_html`)